# EJB3 method calls returning empty objects

Tags: ejb-3.0

I am calling EJB3 service deployed in my jBoss 4.2.3 server from a standalone Java program (using jnp lookup). I have made all my data object Serialized. I have successfully called methods of my EJB but I am losing data from object on client side. I debuged the EJB side within an Application Server and I can see I have data in my objects.

I am calling my EJB using following code;

```
public void doStuff () {

    // Component and its JNDI
    ResourceProviderServiceBeanRemote componentEJB;
    String JNDI_NAME_REMOTE = "ResourceProviderService/ResourceProviderServiceBean/remote";

    // Setup Environment
    Hashtable environment = new Hashtable();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
    environment.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://127.0.0.1:1099"); // remote machine IP
    Context context = null;
    try {
        context = new InitialContext(environment);
        Object factoryObj = context.lookup(JNDI_NAME_REMOTE); //ejb-name
        componentEJB = (ResourceProviderServiceBeanRemote) factoryObj;

        UserContextCallBack userContext = new UserContextCallBackImpl(new UserDetails("username", "password", ""));
        componentEJB.setUserContextCallBack(userContext);

        QueryDetails query = new QueryDetails();
        query.setName("anything");
        List<String> cols = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Row> rows = new ArrayList<Row>();
        ResponseDetails responseDetails = new ResponseDetails();
        componentEJB.doQuery(query, cols, rows, responseDetails);
        System.out.println(responseDetails);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

}

Note: I can see data populated in 'cols', 'rows' and 'responseDetails' on server side but client side remain the same empty initialise objects.

Am I missing anything?

--

SJunejo

Comment: Just to add some more information about serialVersionUID i.e. QueryDetails and Row have serialVersionUID = 1L and ResponseDetails have eclipse auto generated one if that is causing any probelm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a silly mistake, I found out that all the objects are passed by value when calling a methods on any RMI interface. I have to have some Return Type and that's what it is missing. So I am upting my code as follows;

```
// Created a new Response Object by combing all the OUT parameters as one object
// and updated the method on EJB to accept only IN paramters
DoQueryResponse response = componentEJB.doQuery(query);
```

Hope this will help some one (silly) like me :)